# JAXB Marshalling and Unmarshalling with multiple namespaces

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, xml-namespaces

I need your help with JAXB marshalling. It's about namespaces. I have read different blogs and a lot of answers in this amazing site, but I haven't realize how to solve my problem.

I need to generate an XML with some tricky (at least for me) namespaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd" version="3.2" fecha="2016-11-28T11:04:56" sello="MC7" formaDePago="una sola exhibición" noCertificado="00" certificado="MygA" subTotal="615.52" total="714.00" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" LugarExpedicion="México DF" NumCtaPago="3138" TipoCambio="1.00" Moneda="MXN" metodoDePago="04" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3">
<cfdi:Emisor rfc="EMISOR" nombre="EMISOR">
<cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="SIN NUMERO" noExterior="na" municipio="México DF" estado="México" pais="MEX" codigoPostal="15620" />
<cfdi:ExpedidoEn calle="Calle" municipio="México" estado="México" pais="MEX" codigoPostal="63257" />
<cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="GENERAL DE LEY PERSONAS MORALES" />
</cfdi:Emisor>
<cfdi:Receptor rfc="EMPRESA" nombre="EMPRESA">
<cfdi:Domicilio calle="Ave. Esclavitud No. 5300 " municipio="Mexico" pais="MEX" codigoPostal="52478" />
</cfdi:Receptor>
<cfdi:Conceptos>
<cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.0000" unidad="no aplica" noIdentificacion="5213610219" descripcion="CONSUMO" valorUnitario="615.52" importe="615.52" />
</cfdi:Conceptos>
<cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosTrasladados="98.48">
<cfdi:Traslados>
<cfdi:Traslado impuesto="IVA" tasa="16.00" importe="98.48" />
</cfdi:Traslados>
</cfdi:Impuestos>
<cfdi:Complemento>
<tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd" version="1.0" UUID="070A8-5997-4F11-BCEE" FechaTimbrado="2016-11-28T11:05:05" selloCFD="MC7" noCertificadoSAT="20" selloSAT="In2" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" />
</cfdi:Complemento>
<cfdi:Addenda xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.voxelgroup.net/xsd https://www.voxelgroup.net/xsd/addenda_v1.xsd" xmlns:voxel="https://www.voxelgroup.net/xsd">
   <voxel:AdditionalInfo>
   </voxel:AdditionalInfo>
</cfdi:Addenda>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

As you can see, this XML has

`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`

and

`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd"`

and

```
xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"
```

I have done different tests to solve this issue but I haven't had success.

The java class you will see now has been generated with xjc, (not getters and setters for sake of clarity):

```
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "informacionAduanera",
            "cuentaPredial",
            "complementoConcepto",
            "parte"
        })
        @XmlRootElement( name = "Comprobante", namespace = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3")
        public static class Concepto {            
            @XmlElement(name = "InformacionAduanera")
            protected List<TInformacionAduanera> informacionAduanera;
            @XmlElement(name = "CuentaPredial")
            protected Comprobante.Conceptos.Concepto.CuentaPredial cuentaPredial;
            @XmlElement(name = "ComplementoConcepto")
            protected Comprobante.Conceptos.Concepto.ComplementoConcepto complementoConcepto;
            @XmlElement(name = "Parte")
            protected List<Comprobante.Conceptos.Concepto.Parte> parte;
            @XmlAttribute(name = "cantidad", required = true)
            protected BigDecimal cantidad;
            @XmlAttribute(name = "unidad", required = true)
            protected String unidad;
            @XmlAttribute(name = "noIdentificacion")
            protected String noIdentificacion;
            @XmlAttribute(name = "descripcion", required = true)
            protected String descripcion;
            @XmlAttribute(name = "valorUnitario", required = true)
            protected BigDecimal valorUnitario;
            @XmlAttribute(name = "importe", required = true)
            protected BigDecimal importe;
         }
```

And, this is the package-info.class

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", 
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package mx.gob.sat.cfd._3;
```

I have a namespaceMapper too:

```
public class MyNamespaceMapper extends com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper{

    private static final String CFDI_URI = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3";
    private static final String CFDI_PREFIX = "cfdi";
    private static final String XSI_URI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    private static final String XSI_PREFIX = "";//xsi";
    private static final String SCHEMA_URI = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd";
    private static final String SCHEMA_PREFIX = "";//schemaLocation";

    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requiredPrefix) {
        switch(namespaceUri){
            case CFDI_URI:{ return CFDI_PREFIX; }
            case XSI_URI:{ return XSI_PREFIX; }
            case SCHEMA_URI:{ return SCHEMA_PREFIX; }
            default: { return ""; }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, It's the output I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" NumCtaPago="" LugarExpedicion="MEXICO" metodoDePago="02" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" total="4000.00" Moneda="PESO" TipoCambio="1.0000" motivoDescuento="" descuento="0" subTotal="4000" condicionesDePago="EN UNA SOLA EXHIBICION" certificado="" noCertificado="00009200" formaDePago="CHEQUE" sello="" fecha="2016-12-02T12:40:42.302-06:00" folio="9" serie="A" version="3.2">
<xsi:Emisor nombre="PEPITO" rfc="PEPE">
<xsi:DomicilioFiscal codigoPostal="51890" pais="México" estado="México" municipio="México" colonia="México" noInterior="" noExterior="5300" calle="Esclavitud"/>
   <xsi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="Regimen General de Ley Personas Morales"/>
</xsi:Emisor>
<xsi:Receptor nombre="EMPRESA" rfc="EMPRESA">
  <xsi:Domicilio codigoPostal="51890" pais="México" estado="México" municipio="México" colonia="México" noInterior="" noExterior="5300" calle="Esclavitud"/>
</xsi:Receptor>
<xsi:Conceptos>
   <xsi:Concepto importe="4000" valorUnitario="4000" descripcion="ARRENDAMIENTO DEL MES DE SEPTIEMBRE" unidad="N/A" cantidad="1"/>
</xsi:Conceptos>
  <xsi:Impuestos>
   <xsi:Traslados>
      <xsi:Traslado importe="400" tasa="10" impuesto="ISR"/>
    </xsi:Traslados>
  </xsi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

This is the closes I have been from the original xml format.  I have tried differente approaches but I haven't got anything more.

As you can see, in the output still is missing a third namespace,

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd"
```

and every line must have the prefix **cfdi** not *xsi*.

I'll really appreciate any clue to get this done.

Thank you!

Comment: declare the namespace `"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"` in package-info.

Answer (score 1):

As [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html) shows, use the **@XmlNs** annotation to customize the NS prefix.

E.g.

```
   @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "myns",
               namespaceURI="http://myns/schema"
```

The examples will give you more context.

Even if you could get the RI classes to do what you want, it's better to use the APIs than hacking into implementation-only classes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is too late, but I have something like this:

```
...
private Map<String, String> prefijos = new HashMap<String, String>();
prefijos.put("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance","xsi"); 
prefijos.put("http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3", "cfdi");
prefijos.put("http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital", "tfd");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("mx.gob.sat.v33");
marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new 
NamespacePrefixMapperImpl(prefijos));
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION,"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd");

DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
docBuilderFac.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = null;
db = docBuilderFac.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.newDocument();
marshaller.marshal(comprobante,doc);
...
```

My NamespacePrefixMapperImpl is like this:

```
public class NamespacePrefixMapperImpl extends NamespacePrefixMapper{
    private final Map<String, String> map;

    public NamespacePrefixMapperImpl(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, 
                                               boolean requirePrefix) {
        String value = map.get(namespaceUri);
        return (value != null) ? value : suggestion;
    }

    public String[] getPreDeclaredNamespaceUris() {
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

Maybe you can take a look in this [project](https://github.com/estepuma/cfdi33-core)